# Correct way to access a function inside a function of a class, from inside a function inside that class?

Tags: node.js, oop

Whats the classical way to do this?

```
class X {
  a() {
    const findme = () => {}
  }

  b() {
    // how do i call findme from inside here?
  }
}
```

Does it even make sense in an OOP way to do such?

Comment: You can't. `findme` is scoped to the `a` method.

Answer (score 1):

`findme` is in the `a()` scope. You could define a class variable `findme` in `a()` and call it in `b()`:

```
class X {
    a () {
        this.findme = () => {}
    }

    b () {
        this.findme()
    }
}
```